# postgresql for wordpress installation database error

Tags: wordpress, postgresql

I'm struggling to install WordPress on PostgreSQL, which I added alongside MySQL services in Homebrew.

In fact, I've followed the steps from this article many times:
https://medium.com/@shoaibhassan_/install-wordpress-with-postgresql-using-apache-in-5-min-a26078d496fb

When I configure everything as described in the article, I run the installation, and when I click on Install WordPress, I get countless "WordPress database error" messages.

I realized that the tables are actually being created because I can see them in pgAdmin4, but half of what should be filled in is empty, for example, "siteurl" and many others.[image]

[image]